# How to avoid a property/field without any annotation but with name "id" not mapped to '_id' field by Spring Mongo?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

According to [Spring Data Mongo docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/mongo.core.html#mongo.examples-repo)

> The following outlines what property will be mapped to the '_id'
>   document field:
>
> - A property or field annotated with @Id    (org.springframework.data.annotation.Id) will be mapped to the '_id'
>     field.
> - A property or field without an annotation but named id will be    mapped to the '_id' field.

I have some nested classes that have **id** field/property that **does not need** to mapped to mongo `_id` field but rather as a plain `id` field. Any tricks?

Comment: Just annotate the nested class field with @Transient. That should do.

Comment: @orid - I do like to save "id" property as "id" property in Mongo not as "_id" field.

Comment: Have you found the solution? In given mongo schema has real `id` field

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring data mongodb "id" field mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637813/spring-data-mongodb-id-field-mapping)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want that the `id` field is mapped to the mongo `_id` field you have to provide another field in your class with the`@Id` annotation. Then this field is used as mongo id and you can use the other in any way you want.

Example:

```java
public class Foo {

    @Id
    private String mongoId;

    // Your id
    private String id;
}
```

Comment: The better solution is to use this annotation on your id field: `@Field("id")`. Adding an extra field just for this will waste storage space